# Get all record from one table plus the relative last record of a second table

Tags: mysql, sql

Situation (simplified):

**tableA**

```
id  | id_device
----+----------
... | 10
... | 11
... | 12
```

**tableB**

```
id  | id_device | val
----+-----------+----
... | 10        | 200
... | 10        | 105
... | 10        | 120
... | 11        | 80
```

**Result expected:** All the records from `tableA`, and for each record of `tableA`, the last relative record on `tableB`.

```
id_device | val 
----------+-----
10        | 120
11        | 80
12        | null
```

I tried to something like this, but I can't get the last record correctly:

```
SELECT tableA.*,
       tableB.* 
FROM tableA
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT id_device,
           val,
           MAX(id) 
    FROM tableB
    GROUP BY id_device
) AS tableB
     ON tableA.id_device = tableB.id_device
```

Comment: you need to change the ON clause that uses the MAX(id) (alias it first to max_id) from the inner SQL (subquery or deliverd table).  `ON tableA.id_device = tableB.id_device AND tableA.id = tableB.max_id`

Comment: what do you mean that you cannot get the last record correctly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your subquery is selecting the `MAX(d)` from `tableB`, and undetermined values for `id_device` and `val`. It's not selecting the entire record when `MAX(id)`. To do so, you need to select the `MAX(id)` and then join based on it. You can achieve that by using simple descending order and pick the top row:

```
SELECT tableA.id_device, tableB.val
FROM tableA
LEFT JOIN tableB ON tableB.id = (SELECT id
                                 FROM tableB
                                 WHERE tableA.id_device = tableB.id_device
                                 ORDER BY id DESC
                                 LIMIT 1)
```

This allows you to select several fields from `tableB`, but if you're only interested in a single field like `val`, you can also select it directly from the subquery instead of joining on it:

```
SELECT tableA.id_device, (SELECT val
                          FROM tableB
                          WHERE tableA.id_device = tableB.id_device
                          ORDER BY id DESC
                          LIMIT 1) AS val
FROM tableA
```

Comment: This works perfectly. I will use the first one, i have to select several field of table b.